# Download Excel file from database in PHP

Tags: php, html, excel

I have a MariaDB database on a site I am making. In this database, I have a bunch of Excel files that are available for download. For simplicity, lets say I have 5 files. The first named `1.xls`, the second named `2.xls`, and so on.

How can I force a download from the database if a user types the text `4.xls` into a form, then clicks a button? Thanks!

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: You stored excel files in database or files in any folder and stored the path in DB?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I can post my code of me querying the database if that is what you want...

Comment: @noobcode I stored the `.xls` files directly in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force the download of your file, link to *downloadfile.php?filenum=num*

This will be the code in *downloadfile.php*:

```
header('Content-Type: application/xls');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$_GET[filenum].'.xls');
header('Pragma: no-cache'); //if the file change, user will always download the last version
readfile('/path/'.$_GET[filenum].'.xls');
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. The implementation I am actually making is a bit more complex. I am using session variables of usernames to download user reports. But this is what I needed as a start. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you!